# C++ mutlipule .cpp files error c2374

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm working on a winapi graphics wrapper and I've encountered a c2374 error "redefinition; multiple initialization".  I produced an extremely simplified program to illustrate my issue and I'm hoping someone can help me to solve this. NOTE: the code here is only to illustrate to issue, that is why you do not see a cascade of includes.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"
#include "constants.h"


void main()
{
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

functions.h

```
#include "constants.h"
```

functions.cpp

```
#include "functions.h"
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

constants.h

```
double pie = 3.14;
```

constants.cpp

```
#include "constants.h"
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

error is; error C2374: 'pie' : redefinition; multiple initialization

as you can see in this example i'm not trying to edit pie or do anything other than be able to reference the constant from different places. in my graphics wrapper i'm trying to have a HRESULT result; defined so that i can simply test against fails when I initialize directx or sprites, etc.  small request: if you have an answer to this please also point me towards a good textbook to learn about multiple file programming or something, i'm literally teaching myself everything, can't afford classes. thank you.

progress:

the header files now contain a new codeblock

```
#ifndef //stuff//
#def    //stuff//

//code

#endif
```

each with there own unique tag. error changes to LNK2005: "double pie" (?pie@@3NA) already defined in constants.obj.

note: while it was suggested to use const to solve this issue I would like to avoid that as the more complicated program this is representative of needs the variable to be editable.

Comment: Use #pragma once and the *const* keyword.

Comment: Btw, void main doesn't comply with the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the header files that are included are only compiled once - your code will compile constants.h at least twice, as it is included by functions.h and main.cpp. To guarantee this, at the start of each .h file put the statement:

```
#pragma once
```

Note that while widely accepted by compilers, the above is a non-standard option. If you want to adopt a standard supported solution, you can use macro / preprocessor directives, something like this:

```
#ifndef __CONSTANTS_H
#define __CONSTANTS_H 1
//
const double pie = 3.14;
//
#endif
```

Comment: alrighty, I've added the #ifndef stuff to the header files, but the error changes to ( LNK 2005: "double pie" (?pie@@3NA) already defined in constants.obj ). I've tried using an extern prefix on pie but the error doesn't vanish.

Comment: @Okari you probably don't need the constants.cpp file - try without it.

Comment: @Okari you mean it still complains about  a definition of pie in "constants.obj" when you don't have a "constants.cpp" file to compile? That doesn't sound right.... FYI I compiled this no problem in VS2008, using just the two header files and a main.cpp that assigned a variable to the "const pie" value.

Comment: correct, still doesn't like it. the const does make it work, I knew about that, but my goal is not to use it, this isn't the exact code, maybe pie was a bad variable name choice for this, I need to be able to edit pie from other functions spread through the functions and main .cpp's. extern is a prefix I'm aware of, but since this variable is declared and defined in one spot, and not referenced anywhere yet, I'd like to somehow be able to solve this error before I begin applying extern and playing around with secondary declarations..if its even possible.

Comment: @Okari perhaps try making it a 'static double pie' then. You will need to bring back the 'constants.cpp' and define the static variable there as well, but you should end up with only a single definition, and the variable will be mutable by anyone. PS - it would be good practise to wrap the (public) static variable in a static class or a namespace as well.

Comment: the static did not work, replacing it with extern in the .h and then a normal declaration and definition in the .cpp file seems to be the only way to fix it, why is multi-file programming so annoying? i just want to visually organize things, but it brings in so many issues.